# Закрыть доступ к каталогу сайта

Tags: .htaccess, php

Добрый день! Как сделать так, чтобы был закрыт доступ к каталогу сайта, например сайт открывается а когда прописываешь путь **Http://имя_сайта/modules** то он показывает иерархию всего содержимого этого каталога.

Я знаю про фичу `DENY FROM ALL` пишу работает норм, но мне например надо зайти в админ панель пишу **Http://имя_сайта/admin** и он не читает index.php Говорит закрыт доступ. Даже если так пропишу H**ttp://имя_сайта/admin/index.php** напишите пожалуйста подробно как можно открыть доступ к определенным каталогам? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую немного изучить **.htaccess** - **[Хотябы тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165701/)**

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files "closed.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

открывает доступ к файлу... **[.htpasswd и .htaccess](http://www.softtime.ru/info/apache.php?id_article=27)**

а на админ панель лучше поставь пароль,

Comment: На админку поставил пароль, все норм! Попробую сегодня этот способ!